# Remove HTML letters or other characters with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to remove HTML letters, numbers, special characters, etc. with JavaScript?

For instance: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.` Is there a way to make every usage of, for example, the letter 'e' from that sentence with JavaScript?

Comment: What are "HTML letters" and "special characters"?

Comment: By that I meant letters (text) that have been inserted into the page normally with HTML. And special characters meaning '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use replace() method:

```
var string = 'lorem ipsum etc ...';
string = string.replace('e','');
```

First argument can be a regex as well to make it more complex if needed.

Comment: How did I forget this? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the regex to fix that (e.g. `string.replace(/[eE]/gi, "")`)

Answer (score 2):

String replace (optionally using regular expressions).

```
var input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
input.replace(/[eE]/gi, ""); // OR input.replace("e", ""), using whichever regex works best for you
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the `.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)` method:

```
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
var result = str.replace("e", "E");
// result = "LorEm ipsum dolor sit amEt, consEctEtur adipisicing Elit, sEd do Eiusmod tEmpor incididunt ut laborE Et dolorE magna aliqua."
```